# Loads of outgoing udp requests to dns server?

Tags: networking, windows-10, dns

So for some reason my machine is making *tons* of UDP requests on port 53 to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 (google dns).

Is there some way to find out what's causing this? We're trying to clean up traffic on our home network.

Comment: The simplest logical approach is to stop processes one by one until the issue disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out a while ago but forgot to update this question.

Turns out it was just regular DNS requests. Our router doesn't display requests made through the default DNS server, and I was the only person on the network using Google DNS rather than the default. Changed back to default and the mysterious dns spam went away!

Answer (score 0):

We could try to perform a clean boot to troubleshoot whether the issue is related to third party service.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/kb/929135

To troubleshoot this issue deeply, we could use Network Monitor to have a troubleshoot.
Here is the download link:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=4865

Here is a link for reference of using it:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/netmon/p/usagevideos/

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)